# Soundcloud API get reposts from specific user

Tags: api, soundcloud, repost

Iam building a simple Soundcloud API app for myself. I did some research for reposts with API and I figured out that I can only repost tracks with the API but not retrieve them. Is that correct?

What I want to achieve: **Get all Reposted Tracks from a specific username/user_id of soundcloud.**

Is it possible to get this information?
The code to repost a track is:

```
 $repost = json_decode($soundcloud->put('e1/me/track_reposts/<track-id>'), true); // do repost //
```

I hope someone can help me

Answer (score 0):

This is correct. Unfortunately you can't get the information on who reposted a track - or even what tracks you reposted through the api.

From my research your best bet would be to build a small crawler that crawls your page and gets your reposted tracks.  Shouldn't be too hard.